# Ледоскалыватель или льдоскалыватель

Tags: правописание

Подскажите, как правильно говорить, писать: ледоскалыватель или льдоскалыватель. Спасибо.

Comment: @Вяч_слав, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

***ЛЬДОСКАЛЫВАТЕЛЬ***

См. **Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник.** — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/38829/%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C